# calendar and time slots

Tags: calendar, squarespace, appointment, timeslots

I am new to this, I am creating a website for my beauty salon. and would like to add time slots and calendar, can someone help me around it? I have to say, I am not a coder, I am creating the website using Squarespace.

I cannot use the scheduling feature from sqaurespace as they don't support multiple booking.

Comment: If you are not coding, are you in the right spot for your question? This is a site for questions about coding. Wishing you good luck under all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that requires code; There's a built in feature.

Squarespace Scheduling allows you to have multiple calendars so that you can have one for each 'chair' or 'room'. For more information, see [Add and manage calendars](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034677532#toc-add-and-manage-calendars).

If this doesn't suit your needs then you may want to consider embedding a third party booking solution into your Squarespace site. There are a number of these available, some aimed specifically at beauty salons.